# ORDER BY multi-valued field in an Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, multivalue

An intro about why I'm using multi-valued fields that you can skip if you want: I know that multi-valued fields are considered harmful, but I have a really good use for it. I have items that some are in Category A, some are in Category B, and some are in both. Category A and Category B are not used anywhere in the database besides in this one table, and aren't relevant to the rest of the database, and Access's pretty checkbox/combobox is beautiful for selecting the appropriate categories, much better than any other interface I would be able to make with a many-to-many table relationship, or with simply having two separate fields Category A and Category B (especially since its very rare that there are items in both categories).

That being said, I'm having trouble getting the results I want. I have a form that I want the user to be able to select items in a combobox, and I want it to first show all the items that are in Category A (regardless of whether they're also in Category B) and then only afterwards to show all the items that are not in Category A, because Category A items are more likely to be selected by the user so I want them to be more accessible.

I have not been able to manage this. I tried various options of ORDER BY, SELECT DISTINCT, and the like, and I have not been able to work out anything that works for multi-valued fields. Then I tried doing a query that selects all the Category A items, and then another query that selects all the non-Category A items. Each of these queries by themselves work, but Access won't let me UNION them together.

Comment: Welcome to multivalue field in Relational format. If we saw some queries we would be able to help but your question as it stands wont get an answer. Show us some queries and maybe an example row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a table named [Supplier] with sample data

```
ID  CompanyName  Categories
--  -----------  ----------------------
 1  Company 1    Category A
 2  Company 2    Category B
 3  Company 3    Category A, Category B
 4  Company 4    Category B
 5  Company 5    Category A, Category B
```

The query

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CompanyName,
    Categories,
    DCount("*", "Supplier", "ID=" & ID & " AND Categories.Value='Category A'") AS CountCatA
FROM
    Supplier
```

will return

```
ID  CompanyName  Categories              CountCatA
--  -----------  ----------------------  ---------
 1  Company 1    Category A                      1
 2  Company 2    Category B                      0
 3  Company 3    Category A, Category B          1
 4  Company 4    Category B                      0
 5  Company 5    Category A, Category B          1
```

So, instead of using the `DCount()` to populate a column we'll just use it in our ORDER BY clause

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CompanyName,
    Categories
FROM
    Supplier
ORDER BY
    DCount("*", "Supplier", "ID=" & ID & " AND Categories.Value='Category A'") DESC,
    ID
```

returning

```
ID  CompanyName  Categories
--  -----------  ----------------------
 1  Company 1    Category A
 3  Company 3    Category A, Category B
 5  Company 5    Category A, Category B
 2  Company 2    Category B
 4  Company 4    Category B
```

**Edit re: comments**

If you suspect that the `DCount()` function might be slowing things down then you could try this alternative approach using `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    First(CompanyName_) AS CompanyName, 
    First(Categories_) AS Categories
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            CompanyName AS CompanyName_,
            Categories AS Categories_,
            IIf(Categories.Value='Category A',1,0) AS IsPreferredCategory
        FROM Supplier
    )
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY
    SUM(IsPreferredCategory) DESC,
    ID
```

Comment: This worked, so I marked it as the answer, but I do have a small complaint about it - it's very slow. For my small table of about 100 records, it took a few seconds to calculate the query. It's not the end of the world, because I don't expect there to ever be more than about 200 records, but it would be nice if there was a faster solution.

Comment: Of course, the best method would be if we could find some way of using count instead of dcount.

Comment: Amazing! It worked perfectly and ran instantaneously. It took me a while to make sense out of your code and figure out _why_ it works... It's not so far from Albert D. Kallal's answer, but with an added twist.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that most multi-value database systems have the ability to do what is called an exploding selects or sort. Turns out Access also has this ability.

Assume the following query:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, Color FROM customers
WHERE ID = 4
```

Note how the above looks in the query builder:

[image]

NOTE VERY careful in above how the mv column color can be expanded as per above.

The results of the above query are thus:
[image]

Note how results are ONE RECORD, (one row) and a multiple value field of Colors (they are the user’s favorite colors).

Note CLOSE in the query builder you see the column, but note how your can select the child column as “value” (.value).

Thus we now choose this in query builder:
[image]

The resulting sql looks like this:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, Color.Value FROM customers
WHERE ID =4
```

And the results are this:

[image]

NOTE how the ONE row became 3 rows. This in effect is like a LEFT join to the child table. And this means we can SORT on this column.

Thus, simply build a query in which you drop in the .value column and you can then sort + group this data in your report as you asked.

All of Category A items should show first, and then any records with something else will show after. so including .value will explode, or "expand" the resulting query as if it was a sepeate table. You can thus sort your report based on this result.

Comment: I actually tried this already, and the problem is that if something appears in both Category 1 and Category 2, then it appears more than once. I tried selecting unique values only, but Access doesn't allow that when there are multivalue fields involved.

Comment: See Gord Thompson's newly edited answer, which is similar to your answer, but with an added twist to take care of the problem I mentioned.